# How to fix errors in building a book in r bookdown

Tags: r, yaml, bookdown

building my book in R bookdown using the build tab but running into errors

I have updated my R and R Studio to the latest version

```r
---
title: "Lessons for Africa"
subtitle:
- "By"
- "Saanuo"
author: 
- "A thesis submitted to"
- "MASTER’S OF PHILOSOPHY"
- "[FINANCE]"
date: "June, 2020"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: none
    toc: true
    fig_width: 8
    fig_height: 6
    fig_caption: true
mainfont: Timesnewroman
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
toc-depth: 3
lot: True
lof: True
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: library.bib
csl: harvard-educational-review.csl
link-citations: yes
geometry: "left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"

---

\pagenumbering{roman}
# ->Declaration<- {-}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. 

===

# ->Dedication<- {-}

You can also embed plots, for example:


===
# ->Acknowledgement<- {-}

You can also embed plots, for example:


===
# ->Abstract<- {-}

You can also embed plots, for example:


===
# ->Abbreviations<- {-}

library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

data_frame(
  Abbreviation = c("WM", "STM", "LTM"),
  Term = c("Working memory", "Short-term memory", "Long-term memory")) %>%
  arrange(Abbreviation) %>%
  kable(booktab = T)
```

> I wanted to build my book by encountering this error message. Xie please this the my entire index file, as requested. Thank you for your concern. Much appreciated. Hope this helps give my clarity to my problem.

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 19, column 14
Calls: <Anonymous> ... enumerate_output_formats -> yaml_load_file -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: YAML is very picky when it comes to whitespace. I have tried to format it such that the whitespace is visible in your question. Please verify that you see the same formatting.

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible example instead of a fragment. I don't see any problems in this fragment. The problem should be from elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you Ralf, but it doesn't solve my problem. Much grateful anyway.

Comment: Yihui I have provided my entire index file. Hope I well understood your request.  Thank you.